# Calcular porcentagem média de crescimento com PHP

Tags: php, matemática, porcentagem

Tenho o seguinte `json`:

```
{
  "bpi": {
    "2017-10-31": 21094.2212,
    "2017-11-01": 22052.8615,
    "2017-11-02": 22972.5023,
    "2017-11-03": 23730.9012,
    "2017-11-04": 24483.4171,
    "2017-11-05": 24448.8979,
    "2017-11-06": 22610.3597,
    "2017-11-07": 23292.1128,
    }
}
```

Eu precisava pegar e calcular em média, quantos % ele aumenta por dia. Não tenho nenhum código ainda pois ainda não tive a ideia de como fazer esse calculo com o PHP.

Comment: Por exemplo ele vai pegar o dia `31` e comparar com `01` e tem um resultado de `104.54456360778` ou seja, `105%`? eu não entendi bem

Comment: Não somente do dia 01 com 31. Ele tem que ver o crescimento tipo do dia 01 para o dia 02, do dia 02 para 03, etc... e falar que em médio o valor cresce X% ao dia

Comment: Eu não disse só eu disse exemplo, qual é a média então do primeiro dia e do segundo dia?